# What is the difference between a "Reflexive pronoun" and an "Emphatic pronoun"?

Tags: word-meaning, pronouns, reflexive-pronouns, intensive-prounouns

> I did it **myself**.

What is the difference between a "reflexive pronoun" and an "emphatic pronoun"?

What's the definition of "emphatic pronoun"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflexive usages:

- Cats lick themselves to stay clean.
- Dogs lick themselves when hurt.

The reflexive is needed there because without it the cat or dog would be licking a person or food or the ground....

Another interesting one is *wipe oneself* [with toilet paper]. Otherwise you could be wiping a counter.

The reflexive usage in English is there to avoid ambiguity re verbs.

- I find myself thinking about my childhood home in the evenings.
  COMPARE:
- I find much to think about in your essay.
- The child was throwing himself on the bed over and over.
- The child threw himself on the ground and had a tantrum.
  COMPARE:
- The child threw the doll on the ground and stomped off.

WHEREAS: an emphatic pronoun merely emphasizes something about a person in contrast to others or something else:

- He himself thought it was a stupid idea.
- We ourselves would never have voted for that dumb idiot.
- You yourself said you liked French baguettes.
- The worm itself does not live underground though it starts its life there.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two constructs is whether it is *necessary* for the specific meaning (then it's *reflexive*) of the sentence or *can be omitted* without changing the actual meaning (then it's *emphatic*).

In your particular sentence:

> I did it myself.

if you omit "*myself*", then the meaning (that "*it*" was "*done*" by you) still remains:

> I did it.

So, the pronoun is *emphatic*.

A few examples:

> He knocked *himself* out. -- reflexive.
>   He *himself* called the police. -- emphatic
>   They don't consider *themselves* brave. -- reflexive
>   They climbed the mountain all by *themselves*. -- reflexive
>   They climbed the mountain *themselves*. -- emphatic

Comment: Another illustrative pair that might help: *No-one else was willing to quiz the chairman at the AGM, so I asked myself* (emphatic) vs *I asked myself why no-one else was willing to quiz the chairman at the AGM* (reflexive). I think the difference in meaning there is much clearer there than with your *mountain* example (which in any case introduces the extra complexity of ***by***).