# The meaning of "Nuclear scientists are not themselves aware"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, reflexive-pronouns, intensive-prounouns

I am an ESL and preparing GRE exam. In one choice of a question of a reading comprehension passage, there is a sentence like

> (A) Nuclear scientists are not themselves aware of all the facts surrounding the deuterium-tritium fusion reaction

I have difficulty understanding the meaning of **nuclear scientist are not themselves**

Comment: They themselves are not aware... Even nuclear scientists are not aware... *themselves* is used here for emphasis. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/themselves).

Comment: This may help: [What is the difference between a “Reflexive pronoun” and an “Emphatic pronoun”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/71261/9161) If the pronoun is reflexive, it is necessary to the sentence and can't be omitted. If it is emphatic, it can be removed without changing the meaning.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you! Read the sentence like the word 'themselves' never been exist.

Answer (score 1):

In agreement with the comments, I think the meaning here is that most people (non-nuclear scientists) would not be aware of all the facts surrounding the deuterium-tritium fusion reaction, so it is emphasizing that even the nuclear scientists are not either.